# Adding manual gradient to step

Tags: python, pytorch

I was wondering if there was any method to manually add a gradient to a step in pytorch while otherwise using autograd. There is one middle step in my loss function that I cannot compute without transforming the datatype out of a tensor so I don't get an autograd of that component so the gradient doesn't get computed correctly. However, manually I could compute the gradient. How would I go about incorporating this into the gradient graph in pytorch? All the guides I've found don't use autograd at all (as far I understand it).

The specific issue I am trying to solve is normalizing a function over some interval. The following example does this for the sum of gaussians. The tensor m is [[m1,m2,m3,m4...]] and represents means, s represents standard deviations and p represents weights. p,m and s are all outputs from my model. I want the integral between the low and high cutoff to be 1 so I can get that by taking the cdf at higher cutoff and subtracting the lower cutoff cdf before dividing all the ps by that value. I would then use these new values of p (along with m and s and a target) to calculate some value for the loss function. Then when I call loss.backward() I would get the correct gradients, including the part of the gradient that comes from the normalization factor changing as p,m and s change.

```
    normFactor=0
    for gaussianInd in range(numberGaussians):
        normFactor += (spstats.norm.cdf(higherCutoff,m[0][gaussianInd].cpu().detach(),s[0][gaussianInd].cpu().detach()+1e-6)-spstats.norm.cdf(lowerCutoff,m[0][gaussianInd].cpu().detach(),s[0][gaussianInd].cpu().detach()+1e-6))*p[0][gaussianInd]
    p=p/normFactor
```

Edit: Added specific example

Comment: "*that I cannot compute without transforming the datatype out of a tensor*" could you please show some code?

Comment: I will add it to the question, but I am not really sure why it matters. Even if this particular example can be done in pytorch, I would really like an answer to the general question

Comment: The question is unclear as it is. There are several ways to "manually add a gradient to a step", and it would be useful to know what is the particular issue.

Comment: Ahh, understood. Let me know if the little write up above is at all understandable or if I need to clarify further

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can always modify the [`grad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.grad.html) attribute of the tensor of interest. Your optimizer will tap on this attribute to update the corresponding tensor.

---

For illustration purposes:

```
>>> p = nn.Linear(10, 1, bias=False)
>>> p.weight
Parameter containing:
tensor([[ 0.3148, -0.2287,  0.1254, -0.1360,  0.2799, -0.0225, -0.3006, -0.0605,
         -0.2784, -0.2618]], requires_grad=True)

>>> optim = torch.optim.SGD(p.parameters(), lr=.1)
```

Manually modify the gradient:

```
>>> p.weight.grad = torch.rand_like(p.weight)
```

Update with the optimizer:

```
>>> optim.step()
```

The parameter will get updated:

```
>>> p.weight
Parameter containing:
tensor([[ 0.2514, -0.2555,  0.1026, -0.1881,  0.2529, -0.0497, -0.3750, -0.1489,
         -0.3762, -0.2839]], requires_grad=True)
```

Comment: I may be a complete idiot (or have asked this question super poorly) but I still am not totally getting how to combine this with the larger product. How do I combine this with .backward? My issue is that .backward can't compute the gradient of 1 step in the process so I want to put that step into .backward manually. Can I do that simply by creating a tensor with a specific gradient somehow?

Comment: Do you mean you want to implement the backward pass of your computation?

Comment: I don't know how best to word it but yes. I have been using loss.backward() before optim.step(). I am no longer able to do this because I now have a step in the loss function where a number is computed as a float rather than a tensor, which is then multiplied into one of the tensors. Hence this step has no gradient and backwards returns an incorrect answer. I want to make backwards do its thing as it generally does, except for that step where I'd like to specify the gradient. Does that all make sense or am I being too unclear?

Comment: Ok, I understand what you're looking for. Do you actually have the gradient expression of that layer? Have you tried to look into PyTorch functions if you could replace `spstats.norm.cdf` with a builtin/differentiable function? If none of the above, can you explain how your expression works, mathematically speaking?

Comment: I can write a gradient expression for the layer easily I think. I have looked into pytorch functions which could replace cdf with a differentiable function but found nothing suitable (but maybe I missed something easy)

Comment: What my function is doing mathematically is taking an 3 tensors named p,m,s each with N elements and computing the sum of gaussians with means $m_i$ and $s_i$ weighted by $p_i$. However, I want to make the integral over this function 1 within some bounds so I simply integrate over the gaussians with that bounds and divide p by the integral.

Comment: The issue is (as I'm sure is obvious if I've explained well) that taking this integral is kind of hard in pytorch. Fortunately, the cdf which is quickly calculated by scipy is an easy way of doing this. However, this eliminates the ability to keep it as an tensor and therefore gets rid of the gradient

Comment: If no equivalent function is available in PyTorch, you may need to implement the backward pass yourself. By that I mean define the backward function that will be called when backpropagation occurs on that layer. If you can show the python implementation of the gradient of the output of this layer w.r.t to the inputs, then I can help with the PyTorch implementation details.